# TFS mapping gone in solution explorer, but listed correct at Team Explorer

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, team-explorer, solution-explorer

I have a team project that I was working on, but today I opened Visual Studio 2013 (update 2) and my solution, just to see that TFS options (check in, get latest menu options, along with the lock and + signs next to files) are gone. The solution is just like a local solution. I haven't done anything. When I go to team options, I can see that it is mapped to the correct path and I'm on the correct workspace. I've removed the mapping, deleted the solution locally (I didn't have any pending changes) and remapped the solution from TFS. Got the latest version but still no mapping in solution explorer. Restarted Visual Studio many times (obviously), but no avail. I can get the latest from team explorer though. What could be the cause and how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5):

You need to open "File | Source Control | Change Bindings". If the files are in the correct folder you should see a bunch of red squiggles under the mappings.

1. Unbind all of the projects and the solution
2. Rebind all of the projects and the solution

That should solve the issue.

Comment: That option is not available in VS2013 Premium?.

Comment: That option is available in all versions of Visual Studio since 2010. It may be in "File | Source Control | Advanced | Change Bindings" but its around there somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

You might have lost the solution bindings
 Try to re bind to source control. Also check you are in the correct workspace in both places and that you are correctly mapped.

Comment: I've checked the workspace mapping, I am on the correct workspace and in Team Explorer I can see that the solution is actually mapped to the correct path. However, when I open that very solution, it thinks it's not in source control. I've removed the mapping, the folder (fortunatelly I didn't have any pending changes) and re-mapped and performed a get. I've got the latest version, but I still don't have the mapping. I can get latest through team explorer though, just not solution explorer.

Comment: Did you check the bindings? Open the solution file  in a text editor and double check.

Answer (score 1):

Your top source location is mapped into your local folder, check that and remove if that is mapped to the local folder.

```
Right Click -> Advanced -> Remove Mapping
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going to Control Panel -> User Accounts -> Credential Manager and removing several references to a service account that some how became associated with my work space over the weekend. No idea why that happened but removing those associations and restarting visual studio resolved the issue.

The issues I experienced because of this issue are:

- "Out of memory" alert when launching an existing solution that has always worked just fine.
- When "getting latest" on a solution, I would receive an error about our service account not having sufficient permissions to perform the action on my own work space.